# Sybase, SQL: Adding a counter to duplicate values

Tags: sql, sybase, increment

I try to handle the following case. I have a list of entries in the db:

```
Col 1 | Col 2|
------|------|
aaaa  | x    |
aaaa  | x    |
bbbb  | y    |
cccc  | z    |
cccc  | z    |
```

The goal is to identify the duplicates in Col 1 and add a number to each line and for the duplicates the number should incremented so that we get also unique entries. After each new entry the counter should start from 1 again.

```
Col 1   | Col 2 |
--------|-------|
aaaa-1  | x     |
aaaa-2  | x     |
bbbb-1  | y     |
cccc-1  | z     |
cccc-2  | z     |
```

Do you have any idea how to manage this?

Best regards,

Dirk

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Which Sybase RDBMS product (ASE, SQLAnywhere, IQ, Advantage) are you using?

Comment: You've stated in a comment (below) that you've tried a cursor and while-loop/temp-table; consider adding these attempted solutions to your original question ... it may be easier to tweak what you've got than to start over from scratch (especially since you've not provided any details on table/column names)

Answer (score 0):

I would try this. I hope that solves your issue.

```
     SELECT COL1 + ' - ' + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY COL1 ORDER BY COL1) as COL_A
          , COL2 AS COL_B
     FROM TABLE
```

Depending on the DBMS you are working with, you might have to CAST `ROW_NUMBER()`. I tried that on Oracle 11.2 and it worked properly:

```
   SELECT  COL1 || ' - ' || ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY COL1 ORDER BY COL1)  AS COL_A
         , COL2 AS COL_B
   FROM TABLENAME
```

Comment: I've tried it with a cursor - but somehow stuck at the end without an usable result. After that I've tried while loop combined with a temp table. Also a dead end :-(

Comment: You might be lucky with [that link](http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?1616373-Sybase-s-ROWNUM-function) they were facing the same issue and there might be an aquivalent to `ROW_NUMBER()` calles `ROWID` on sybase

Answer (score 0):

**Hi Dirk,**

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Col1,Col2,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1,Col2 
                                       ORDER BY ( SELECT 0)) RN
         FROM   tableName)
select Col1+'-'+convert(varchar,rn) as Col1,Col2 FROM cte
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Unfortunatly the current version of the Sybase server is 15.0.3 => and Row_number() seams to be not supported :-((